# How do i display only 5 Li's and have a button that displays 5 more

Tags: jquery

I have 500 `li`'s but I only want to show 5 at first, then I can click a button and that shows me more `li`'s and maybe at the end there are no more `li`'s but not all of them just another 5?

Comment: i have tryed some thing but and it displays 5 li's but when i click the show more it displays all the over and i only wan it to display 5 more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could dynamically add a "more" button after your `ul` and show 5 li's at a time until all are shown. Then you could hide the more button:

```
var vis = 5;
$('li').slice(vis).hide();

var $more = $('<a href="#">test</a>')
$more.click(function(){
    $('li:hidden').slice(0,vis).show();
    if($('li:hidden').length == 0)
        $more.hide();
});
$('ul').after($more);
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/JKWtP/

Answer (score 5):

```
var $li = $("li"),
    chunk = 5;

$li.slice(chunk).hide();

$("button").click(function() {
    $li.filter(":hidden").slice(0, chunk).show();
});​
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ma8AW/).

There are more efficient ways to write this code, but this one is fairly readable.

Comment: @refhat - I dont necessarily disagree, but could you elaborate on why you think that? The 2 answers are almost identical.

Comment: @Jamiec Agreed they are 99% identical, But this one has lesser code, coherent and more readable and of course doesn't depend on markup